Doubt about a proof a maximum principle for elliptical operator
I am currently revising a PDE program and working through Jürgen Jost's Partial Differential Equations. I encountered a doubt regarding the proof of Theorem 3.1.1.
Theorem 3.1.1
Assume $c(x) \equiv 0$, and let $u$ satisfy in $\Omega$
$$
Lu \geq 0,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^{d} a^{ij}(x) u_{x_i x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^{d} b^i(x) u_{x_i} \geq 0. \tag{3.1.2}
$$
Then also
$$
\sup_{x \in \Omega} u(x) = \max_{x \in \partial \Omega} u(x). \tag{3.1.3}
$$
In the case $Lu \leq 0$, a corresponding result holds for the infimum.
Proof
As in the proof of Lemma 3.1.1, we first consider the case
$$
Lu > 0.
$$
Since at an interior maximum $x_0$ of $u$, we must have
$$
u_{x_i}(x_0) = 0 \quad \text{for } i = 1, \ldots, d,
$$
and
$$
\left( u_{x_i x_j}(x_0) \right)_{i,j = 1, \ldots, d} \quad \text{is negative semidefinite,}
$$
and thus, by the ellipticity condition, also
$$
Lu(x_0) = \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} a^{ij}(x_0) u_{x_i x_j}(x_0) \leq 0.
$$
Such an interior maximum cannot occur.

Question
Why does the fact that $\left( u_{x_i x_j}(x_0) \right)_{i,j= 1, \dots, d}$ is negative semidefinite imply that $Lu(x_0) \leq 0$? How exactly does this property
$$
\xi^i \cdot u_{x_i x_j}(x_0) \cdot \xi^j \geq 0 \quad \text{for all } \xi \in \mathbb{R}^{d}, \quad i,j=1,\dots, d
$$
lead to this inequality? Shouldn't we also be using Hopf's Lemma here to derive the desired conclusion?

Denote $A = [a^{ij}]$, and $D^2u = [u_{x_ix_j}]$.
Let $D^2u = Q\Lambda Q^T$ be an eigenvalue decomposition of the Hessian matrix $D^2u$, where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix filled with eigenvalues of $D^2u$, i.e.
$$\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_d).$$
This decomposition is possible because $D^2u$ is symmetric. The orthogonal matrix $Q$ has some nice properties that will become useful:
(1) $Q^TQ = I$.
(2) $tr(B) = tr(Q^TBQ)$ for any matrix $B$ with the appropriate dimensions.
Define $\tilde{A} = [\tilde{a^{ij}}] := Q^TAQ$. Since $A$ is (uniformly) elliptic, let $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^d$, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j=1}^d \tilde{a^{ij}} \xi_i \xi_j &= \xi^T \tilde{A} \xi \\
&= \xi^T Q^T A Q\xi \\
&= (Q\xi)^T A (Q\xi) \\
&\geq \theta|\xi|^2>0.
\end{align}
In other words, $\tilde{A}$ is also (uniformly) elliptic. In particular, if the $\xi$ is chosen to be the $i$-th unit vector, then $\tilde{a^{ii}}>0$ for all $i$. (Or, $\tilde{A}$ is positive definite and hence its diagonal entries are all positive).
Now back to $Lu(x_0)$. Since $u_{x_i}(x_0)=0$ for all $i$,
\begin{align}
Lu(x_0) &= \sum_{i,j=1}^d a^{ij}(x_0) u_{x_ix_j}(x_0)\\
&= tr(AD^2u)\\
&= tr(AQ\Lambda Q^T)\\
&= tr(Q^T AQ\Lambda Q^TQ) \quad \text{(property (2))}\\
&= tr(Q^T AQ\Lambda) \quad \text{(property (1))}\\
&= tr(\tilde{A}\Lambda)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^d \tilde{a^{ii}} \lambda_i.
\end{align}
Since the above equation is evaluated at $x_0$, and $D^2u$ is negative-semidefinite at $x_0$, we therefore know that all $\lambda_i$'s are non-positive. Therefore $Lu(x_0)\leq 0$ and that is a contradiction (to the strict inequality $Lu>0$ case).
Here is a link to the source on which this answer is based: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~qze/notes/ELLIPTIC%20PDE/wmp.pdf.
